# Django Model - Auto Referencing

Tags: django, django-models, orm

```
class BusinessUnit(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'carecode_business_unit'
    parent_business_unit = models.ForeignKey(BusinessUnit)
```

"BusinessUnit" is not defined.

Is it possible to create an auto-referencing model in Django?

Answer (score 1):

```
class BusinessUnit(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'carecode_business_unit'
    parent_business_unit = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class BusinessUnit(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'carecode_business_unit'
    parent_business_unit = models.ForeignKey("BusinessUnit", on_delete=models.set_NULL)
```

Add quotes around the model. You can't reference the parent class directly, but django can lazy load it with quotes.